# Checking if results of F object are greater than zero

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Is it possible to filter only records that have a field that, after `bitand` is greater than zero? Something like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(F('some_field').bitand(4) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.8 (currently unreleased), you should be able to `annotate` using `F()` objects ([see this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030)).

If you're still in development, or have the time to wait for Django 1.8 to ship, then you could try and annotate using `F()`, and  then [filter on the annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations):

```
MyModel.objects.\
  annotate(some_annotated_field=F('some_field').bitand(4)).\
  filter(some_annotated_field__gt = 0)
```

This is part of the new ["Query Expressions" feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/) in Django 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider raw SQL like

```
     MyModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel WHERE (col & 4) >0;')
```